# Create new user when place order woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, zapier

I tried create a new user account when place order trough Zapier -> Woocommerce
I have the following code:

```
// Get $order object
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

// Get the user email from the order
$order_email = $order->get_billing_email();

// Check if there are any users with the billing email as user or email
$email = email_exists( $order_email );  
$user = username_exists( $order_email );

// If the UID is null, then it's a guest checkout (new user)
if ( $user == false && $email == false ) {
    // Random password with 12 chars
    $random_password = wp_generate_password();
    
    // Firstname
    $first_name = $order->get_billing_first_name();
    
    // Lastname
    $last_name = $order->get_billing_last_name();
    
    // Role
    $role = 'customer';

    // Create new user with email as username, newly created password and userrole          
    $user_id = wp_insert_user(
        array(
            'user_email' => $order_email,
            'user_login' => $order_email,
            'user_pass'  => $random_password,
            'first_name' => $first_name,
            'last_name'  => $last_name,
            'role'       => $role,
        )
    );
    
    // Get all WooCommerce emails Objects from WC_Emails Object instance
    $emails = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();

    // Send WooCommerce "Customer New Account" email notification with the password
    $emails['WC_Email_Customer_New_Account']->trigger( $user_id, $random_password, true );

    // (Optional) WC guest customer identification
    //update_user_meta( $user_id, 'guest', 'yes' );

    // User's billing data
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_1', $order->get_billing_address_1() );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_2', $order->get_billing_address_2() );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_city', $order->get_billing_city() );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_company', $order->get_billing_company() );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_country', $order->get_billing_country() );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_email', $order_email );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_first_name', $order->get_billing_first_name() );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_last_name',  $order->get_billing_last_name() );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', $order->get_billing_phone() );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_postcode', $order->get_billing_postcode() );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_state', $order->get_billing_state() );

    // User's shipping data
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_address_1', $order->get_shipping_address_1() );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_address_2', $order->get_shipping_address_2() );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_city', $order->get_shipping_city() );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_company', $order->get_shipping_company() );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_country', $order->get_shipping_country() );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_first_name', $order->get_shipping_first_name() );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_last_name', $order->get_shipping_last_name() );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_method', $order->get_shipping_method() );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_postcode', $order->get_shipping_postcode() );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_state', $order->get_shipping_state() );

    // Link past orders to this newly created customer
    wc_update_new_customer_past_orders( $user_id );
    
    // Auto login
    wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
}
```

}

I trigger this action when place a new order?
I tried whit order status processig hook and woocommerce status changed hook and not working.

Does anyone have an idea?

I think the code is well done but I don't understand why it doesn't work with those hooks

Thanks in advance for all!

Comment: In addition to my answer you can just mark create account checkbox,hide the fields and fill em with random password and grab the email from billing. Keep in mind if you sell in EU this is against the laws both option.

Answer (score 0):

I did a small changes to your function try this. Tested and its working

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'test',10,1);
function test($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    //Check if customer is guest 
    if($order->get_customer_id() == 0) {
        // Get the user email from the order
        $order_email = $order->get_billing_email();

        // Random password with 12 chars
        $random_password = wp_generate_password();
        
        // Firstname
        $first_name = $order->get_billing_first_name();
        
        // Lastname
        $last_name = $order->get_billing_last_name();
        
        // Role
        $role = 'customer';

        // Create new user with email as username, newly created password and userrole          
        $user_id = wp_insert_user(
            array(
                'user_email' => $order_email,
                'user_login' => $order_email,
                'user_pass'  => $random_password,
                'first_name' => $first_name,
                'last_name'  => $last_name,
                'role'       => $role,
            )
        );
        
        // Get all WooCommerce emails Objects from WC_Emails Object instance
        $emails = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();

        // Send WooCommerce "Customer New Account" email notification with the password
        $emails['WC_Email_Customer_New_Account']->trigger( $user_id, $random_password, true );

        // (Optional) WC guest customer identification
        //update_user_meta( $user_id, 'guest', 'yes' );

        // User's billing data
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_1', $order->get_billing_address_1() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_2', $order->get_billing_address_2() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_city', $order->get_billing_city() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_company', $order->get_billing_company() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_country', $order->get_billing_country() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_email', $order_email );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_first_name', $order->get_billing_first_name() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_last_name',  $order->get_billing_last_name() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', $order->get_billing_phone() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_postcode', $order->get_billing_postcode() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_state', $order->get_billing_state() );

        // User's shipping data
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_address_1', $order->get_shipping_address_1() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_address_2', $order->get_shipping_address_2() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_city', $order->get_shipping_city() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_company', $order->get_shipping_company() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_country', $order->get_shipping_country() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_first_name', $order->get_shipping_first_name() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_last_name', $order->get_shipping_last_name() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_method', $order->get_shipping_method() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_postcode', $order->get_shipping_postcode() );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'shipping_state', $order->get_shipping_state() );

        // Link past orders to this newly created customer
        wc_update_new_customer_past_orders( $user_id );
        
        // Auto login
        wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, friend!
I'll try the code right away and let you know.